# ListView maintain checkbox condition when scrolling and rotating

Tags: java, android

My application was created in a simplified matters and in the end it looks like it backfired me as I was unable to maintain the condition of the application on scrolling and rotating. I have attempted to maintain the checkbox condition using the following code but after I repeated scrolling for over 2 times or so, the checkboxes will be unchecked again. It seemed to be working for only the first scroll. I have seen other people solving this problem by using things like view holders and restore instance to maintain condition when rotating but I'm interested to know that if there are solutions for my problems. I try to include my code as short as possible

MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    selections = new ArrayList<String>();
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    final mAdapter adapter = new mAdapter(this, imgid, cityname, countryname);
    LV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    LV.setAdapter(adapter);

    LV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String selected = cityname[+position];
            CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            if (selections.contains(selected) || checkbox.isChecked()){
                selections.remove(selected);
                checkbox.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                selections.add(selected);
                checkbox.setChecked(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

mAdapter

```
public class mAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Activity context;
private final Integer[] imgid;
private final String[] cityname, countryname;
private List<Integer> selectedItemsPositions = new ArrayList<>();

public mAdapter(Activity context, Integer[] imgid, String[] cityname, String[] countryname) {
    super(context, R.layout.row, cityname);
    this.context = context;
    this.imgid = imgid;
    this.cityname = cityname;
    this.countryname = countryname;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null, true);

    ImageView icon = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.cityicon);
    TextView city = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.city);
    TextView country = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.country);
    final CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

    icon.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
    city.setText(cityname[position]);
    country.setText(countryname[position]);

    checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            int position = (int)buttonView.getTag();
            if (!selectedItemsPositions.contains(position))
                selectedItemsPositions.add(position);
            else {
                selectedItemsPositions.remove(position);
            }
        }
    });

    checkbox.setTag(position);
    if (selectedItemsPositions.contains(position))
        checkbox.setChecked(true);
    else
        checkbox.setChecked(false);

    return rowView;
}
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Calling `setChecked()` calls the listener. This means, if item should be checked according to `selectedItemsPositions` it is checked which in turn calls the listener which removes the position from `selectedItemsPositions`.

Solution:

In the listener, use `isChecked` to decide how to modify `selectedItemsPositions`. Roughly:

```
        if (isChecked && !selectedItemsPositions.contains(position))
            selectedItemsPositions.add(position);
        else if (!isChecked && selectedItemsPositions.contains(position))
            selectedItemsPositions.remove(position);
```